# C to Assembly Conversion datatype sizes

Tags: c, assembly

According to this article: [link](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)

In this c simple program:

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
        char x[10];
}

void main() {
        function(1, 2, 3);
}
```

i get assembly file using this command:

```
gcc -m32 -S -o example1.s example1.c
```

and that is the result for function (function):

```
function:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        subl    $16, %esp
        nop
        leave
        .cfi_restore 5
        .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

my question is why this line became:

```
subl    $16, %esp
```

where i expect it to be:

```
subl    $10, %esp
```

i use kali linux 64

vendor_id       : GenuineIntel

model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 350  @ 2.27GHz

Architecture:          x86_64

CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit

Byte Order:            Little Endian

Comment: It was probably optimized out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually stack alignment.

From the [gcc(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) manual:

> -mpreferred-stack-boundary=num
>
> Attempt to keep the stack boundary aligned to a 2 raised to num byte boundary.  If -mpreferred-stack-boundary is not specified, the default is 4 (16 bytes or 128 bits).

GCC is aligning the base of the stack such that it rests on a 16 byte boundary.

The actual layout is:

```
x[9]
...
x[0]
padding[5]
...
padding[0] <-- $esp
```

Comment: so it should be `subl $12, %esp` not `subl $16, %esp`?

Comment: Where are you getting 12? 2^4 is 16. If you try to allocate 17 bytes, you get `subl $32, %esp`.

Comment: thanx Stebalien, i got it!